# image should overlap on given shape

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

i tried to overlap the white  circle type shape with image taken from camera ,or image taken from gallery ,below are the code for that  , i struck in performing this step.xaml code and its cs code is given image is also provided forrefrences
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSf08.png)

```
 <Grid Name="SignUpView">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/info_bg.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="rowDefHeadingGrid" Height="2.8*"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="rowDefFormFillGrid" Height="4.4*"/>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="rowDefFooterGrid" Height="0.8*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#339FFE">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Width="354"  Height="336">
                <Image Source="Assets\back_bg.png" Name="backImg"  Width="40" Height="35"  Margin="-280,16,0,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="Sign up" Foreground="White" FontSize="22" Margin="69,-36,192,145"/>
                <Image Source="Assets\pro_pic_box.png" Width="115" Height="95" Margin="117,-218,100,-30" />

                <Canvas>
                    <Image Name="imageControl" Source="Assets\pro_pic.png" Margin="161,-107,10,10" Height="60" Width="50"/>

                    <Image Source="Assets\ic_profile_pic_edit.png" Margin="205,-77,10,10" Height="13" Width="13" Tapped="cameraClick">
                        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom">
                                <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="53,-10,0,0" />
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E84C3D" />
                                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="7" />
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="160"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Open Camera" Click="camOpen"  FontSize="10" Padding="3,3,3,3" />
                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Choose from Gallery" Click="chooseGall"  FontSize="10" Padding="3,3,3,3"/>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Cancel" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click"  FontSize="10" Padding="3,3,3,3"/>
                            </MenuFlyout>
                        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                    </Image>
                    <StackPanel>
                    <CaptureElement Height="450" Name="captureElement"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="9" Margin="50,5,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="loading" VerticalAlignment="Center">Loading...</TextBlock>
                </Canvas>
                <TextBox x:Name="emailBox1" Text="user name" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" BorderBrush="White"  Background="#339EFC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="260"  Margin="55,-60,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" />               
            </StackPanel>            
        </Grid>
```

.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.Media.Capture;
using Windows.Media.MediaProperties;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace CustomSplash
{
 public sealed partial class signup : Page
    {
 public signup()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
   private void cameraClick(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(sender as FrameworkElement);
}
 private async void camOpen(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CameraCaptureUI captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
            captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
            captureUI.PhotoSettings.CroppedSizeInPixels = new Size(200, 200);

            StorageFile photo = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
            if (photo != null)
            {
                await ProcessFile(photo);
                await photo.MoveAsync(KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary);
            }

        }

        private async void chooseGall(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var openPicker = new FileOpenPicker
            {
                ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
                SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
            };
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            var photo = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

            if (photo != null)
            {
                await ProcessFile(photo);
            }
        }

        private void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          imageControl.Source= new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/pro_pic.png", UriKind.Absolute));
        }
        private async Task ProcessFile(StorageFile photo)
        {
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await photo.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
            SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();

            SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmapBGR8 = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

            SoftwareBitmapSource bitmapSource = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
            await bitmapSource.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmapBGR8);

            imageControl.Source = bitmapSource;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a [Ellipse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.ellipse.aspx) with [ImageBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imagebrush.aspx) filled instead of using the `imageControl`. Set the [fill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.shape.fill.aspx) property of Ellipse with a ImageBrush and when you change the picture, update the [ImageSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imagebrush.imagesource.aspx) property of the ImageBrush.

Code changed based on your code as follows:

```
<!--<Image Name="imageControl" Source="Assets\pro_pic.png" Margin="161,-107,10,10" Height="60" Width="50"/>--> 
<Ellipse  Height="50"  Width="50" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="161,-107,10,10" >
     <Ellipse.Fill>
         <ImageBrush  x:Name="imageControl"   ImageSource="Assets\pro_pic.png"  />
     </Ellipse.Fill>
 </Ellipse>
```

.cs

```
 private async Task ProcessFile(StorageFile photo)
 {
     IRandomAccessStream stream = await photo.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
     BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
     SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();

     SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmapBGR8 = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

     SoftwareBitmapSource bitmapSource = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
     await bitmapSource.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmapBGR8);
     imageControl.ImageSource= bitmapSource;
     //imageControl.Source = bitmapSource;
 }
```

Comment: By the way, I saw you use many margin for position elements, I recommend you to use the layout control itself instead of margin setting. For more details about layout you can reference:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/index

Comment: Thnx.. i will take care of it.but how to crop the image and then fit it to proper circular shape.